# Can I add and remove elements of enumeration at runtime in Java

Tags: java, enums

It is possible to add and remove elements from an enum in Java at runtime?

For example, could I read in the labels and constructor arguments of an enum from a file?

---

@saua, it's just a question of whether it can be done out of interest really. I was hoping there'd be some neat way of altering the running bytecode, maybe using [BCEL](http://bcel.sourceforge.net/) or something. I've also followed up with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481068/when-to-use-enum-or-collection-in-java) because I realised I wasn't totally sure when an enum should be used.

I'm pretty convinced that the right answer would be to use a collection that ensured uniqueness instead of an enum if I want to be able to alter the contents safely at runtime.

Comment: Usually, if you want this, you're misusing them. Could you tell us what you need that for?

Comment: My answer was implemented with a HashMap behind the scenes, so you can ensure uniqueness.

Comment: FWIW, it helps test default cases for switch on enums.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

No, enums are supposed to be a complete static enumeration.

At compile time, you might want to generate your enum .java file from another source file of some sort. You could even create a .class file like this.

In some cases you might want a set of standard values but allow extension. The usual way to do this is have an `interface` for the interface and an `enum` that implements that `interface` for the standard values. Of course, you lose the ability to `switch` when you only have a reference to the `interface`.

Comment: Would you know where can I find a good example of an enum implementing such interface? I will be interested in such functionality.

Comment: @megalucio I think I was thinking of `java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/StandardOpenOption.html but there's also `java.net.StandardProtocolFamily` and `javax.tools.StandardLocation`.

Comment: Thanks very much . I will have a look into it.

Answer (score 13):

Behind the curtain, enums are POJOs with a private constructor and a bunch of public static final values of the enum's type (see [here](http://snipplr.com/view/1655/typesafe-enum-pattern/) for an example). In fact, up until Java5, it was considered best-practice to build your own enumeration this way, and Java5 introduced the `enum` keyword as a shorthand. See the source for [Enum<T>](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/Enum.java.html) to learn more.

So it should be no problem to write your own 'TypeSafeEnum' with a public static final array of constants, that are read by the constructor or passed to it.

Also, do yourself a favor and override `equals`, `hashCode` and `toString`, and if possible create a `values` method

The question is how to use such a dynamic enumeration... you can't read the value "PI=3.14" from a file to create `enum MathConstants` and then go ahead and use `MathConstants.PI` wherever you want...

Comment: Never write a public static non-empty array field - they are not constant.

Comment: Is that true? As the instance on the end of the reference is immutable, I'm not sure how you could actually change it... is it just crossed wires over whether it's an array instance or not?

Comment: Collections and Arrays are both mutable Objects (and "Objects").  Having a "final" array just means you're not going to resize or otherwise reassign the array, but it still lets you replace values that already fit in its bounds.

Answer (score 12):

I needed to do something like this (for unit testing purposes), and I came across this - the EnumBuster:
http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue161.html

It allows enum values to be added, removed and restored.

**Edit**: I've only just started using this, and found that there's some slight changes needed for java 1.5, which I'm currently stuck with:

- Add array copyOf static helper methods (e.g. take these 1.6 versions: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Arrays.java.html)
- Change EnumBuster.undoStack to a Stack`<Memento>`

  - In undo(), change undoStack.poll() to undoStack.isEmpty() ? null : undoStack.pop();
- The string VALUES_FIELD needs to be "ENUM$VALUES" for the java 1.5 enums I've tried so far

Comment: With modern versions of Java, you need to change a few things as documented in the revised article: https://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue272-Hacking-Enums-Revisited.html

Answer (score 6):

I faced this problem on the [formative project of my young career](http://moffdub.wordpress.com/2008/04/28/introducing-the-project/).

The approach I took was to save the values and the names of the enumeration externally, and the end goal was to be able to write code that looked as close to a language enum as possible.

I wanted my solution to look like this:

```
enum HatType
{
    BASEBALL,
    BRIMLESS,
    INDIANA_JONES
}

HatType mine = HatType.BASEBALL;

// prints "BASEBALL"
System.out.println(mine.toString());

// prints true
System.out.println(mine.equals(HatType.BASEBALL));
```

And I ended up with something like this:

```
// in a file somewhere:
// 1 --> BASEBALL
// 2 --> BRIMLESS
// 3 --> INDIANA_JONES

HatDynamicEnum hats = HatEnumRepository.retrieve();

HatEnumValue mine = hats.valueOf("BASEBALL");

// prints "BASEBALL"
System.out.println(mine.toString());

// prints true
System.out.println(mine.equals(hats.valueOf("BASEBALL"));
```

Since my requirements were that it had to be possible to add members to the enum at run-time, I also implemented that functionality:

```
hats.addEnum("BATTING_PRACTICE");

HatEnumRepository.storeEnum(hats);

hats = HatEnumRepository.retrieve();

HatEnumValue justArrived = hats.valueOf("BATTING_PRACTICE");
// file now reads:
// 1 --> BASEBALL
// 2 --> BRIMLESS
// 3 --> INDIANA_JONES
// 4 --> BATTING_PRACTICE
```

I dubbed it the Dynamic Enumeration "pattern", and you read about [the original design](http://moffdub.wordpress.com/2008/05/09/dynamic-enumerations/) and [its revised edition](http://moffdub.wordpress.com/2009/01/14/dynamic-enumerations-revisited/).

The difference between the two is that the revised edition was designed after I really started to grok OO and DDD. The first one I designed when I was still writing nominally procedural DDD, under time pressure no less.

Comment: the links in your post are now protected by the author and not viewable

Comment: Doesn't this break best practices for Java which assumes that Enumerators are static and final? It's almost like you're using a local file as a database of constant values that must be read fresh to guarantee latest as previously read data could be stale.

Answer (score 1):

You can load a Java class from source at runtime. (Using JCI, BeanShell or JavaCompiler)

This would allow you to change the Enum values as you wish.

Note: this wouldn't change any classes which referred to these enums so this might not be very useful in reality.

Answer (score 1):

A working example in widespread use is in modded Minecraft. See EnumHelper.addEnum() methods on [Github](https://github.com/MinecraftForge/MinecraftForge/blob/1.12.x/src/main/java/net/minecraftforge/common/util/EnumHelper.java#L257-#L430)

However, note that **in rare situations** practical experience has shown that adding Enum members can lead to some issues with the JVM optimiser.  The exact issues may vary with different JVMs.  But broadly it seems the optimiser may assume that some internal fields of an Enum, specifically the size of the Enum's `.values()` array, will not change.  See [issue discussion](https://github.com/MinecraftForge/MinecraftForge/issues/3885).  The recommended solution there is not to make `.values()` a hotspot for the optimiser.  So if adding to an Enum's members at runtime, it should be done once and once only when the application is initialised, and then the result of `.values()` should be cached to avoid making it a hotspot.

The way the optimiser works and the way it detects hotspots is obscure and may vary between different JVMs and different builds of the JVM.  If you don't want to take the risk of this type of issue in production code, then don't change Enums at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to assign properties to the ENUM you're trying to create and statically contruct it by using a loaded properties file. Big hack, but it works :)