# What is Enum useful for?

Tags: java, enums

After reading some questions and answers about enum I don't find it really useful...

It's something between class and a variable but I know where can I use it so it would be more useful then a class, or a couple of variables for example.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/481068/when-to-use-enum-or-collection-in-java

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077634/enum-in-java-advantages

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There are other things you can do and reasons to use them, but the primary reason I use enums is to prevent the possibility of an invalid parameter. For example, imagine the following method:

```
public void doSomethingWithAMonth(int monthNum);
```

This is not only ambiguous (do month indexes start at 1, or at 0?), but you can give down-right invalid data (13+, negative numbers). If you have an enum `Month` with JAN, FEB, etc. the signature becomes:

```
public void doSomethignWithAMonth(Month month);
```

Code calling this method will be far more readable, and can't provide invalid data.

Comment: Thanks! Now I think I understand it little better :)

Comment: That is a simple and good example

Answer (score 10):

I use Enums for anything that has multiple nonchanging "type" of something. i.e days of a week.

Why I don't use String in this case is because I can't do switch statement on the String and I can on Enum so for every day of a week I can do something specific.

I also use Enum when working with singleton pattern, Check the [Effective Java book CH2(CHAPTER 2 CREATING AND DESTROYING OBJECTS)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683), quote :

"While this approach has yet to be widely
adopted, a single-element enum type is the best way to implement a singleton." not gonna paste code read the book it's excellent.

If I were you I'd firstly read [Thinking in java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131872486) chapter Enumerated Types. Then after that Effective Java chapter 6 and you should be good

Answer (score 9):

Simplest Definition - `An enum is just like any other class, with a predefined set of instances.`

Best part of enum is it can be used in switch statements where we can't use Strings.

and Enum is a safe-type so you can't assign a new value at the runtime.

Comment: Just for anyone coming across this, as of Java 7, it's no longer true that you can't use `String`s in `switch` statements. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/strings-switch.html

Answer (score 4):

An `enum` forces coders to select from a pre-defined list of entities or concepts. Whilst you could achieve the same objective with classes or setting a variable to a particular known value, an enumeration is less error-prone as it advertises and enforces a menu from which the setter of a value can pick.

Answer (score 4):

An Enum is useful to prevent people from doing things they shouldn't do. For example, if I have:

```
public final static int WEATHER_SUNNY = 0;
public final static int WEATHER_RAINY = 1;
public final static int WEATHER_HAIL = 2;
```

then I can do: `MyClass.WEATHER_SUNNY + MyClass.WEATHER_HAIL` which makes no sense. That's why it's better to have a Weather enum. This makes the code more readable and it disallows summing two weather integers.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of this example if only for the reason that I feel it encourages narrow-minded thinking. There's no reason different weather types like this can't overlap, in fact, they frequently do.

Comment: @Thor84no: thanks for your comment. However, this all depends on the domain and application so saying things like "encourages narrow-minded thinking." doesn't seem appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

I would add to the other answers that enums are classes which only have a fixed number of instances. These instances may have fields and methods, and be used as any other Java objects. For example, the `Month` enum could define methods like

```
public int getNumberOfDays(int year);
public boolean isFirstOfYear();
```

Answer (score 2):

As goes from the name "enum" it is ideal for enumeration constants, which provide extended functionality. As for example you can store some constants comprising from several parameters like: constantId, constanNameString, additional params. Additionally enum can contain functions.

An exotic use of enum is to make a singleton.

Answer (score 2):

Enum is useful when you have a list of values that are functionnally significant and finite.

Say for exemple that you need to use a day of the week : another day won't be added and you'd rather have Day.MONDAY in your code rather than a number and having to remember that 0 is monday, 1 is tuesday and so on.
It makes switch statement easier to understand too, with :

```
Switch(day) { 
  case Monday : ... break;
  case Tuesday : ... break
  etc.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Among other things, an Enum is useful to create singletons:

[What is an efficient way to implement a singleton pattern in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689/efficient-way-to-implement-singleton-pattern-in-java)