# How to change an enum at runtime (Java)

Tags: java, enums, minecraft-forge

Basically, I am writing an addon for a Minecraft mod called Aura Cascade. 
Aura Cascade adds aura (as the name suggests), which comes in different colors. I wanted to add some colors of aura, but the valid colors are defined in an enum like this:

```
public enum EnumAura{WHITE,BLACK,RED,ORANGE,YELLOW,GREEN,BLUE,PURPLE}
```

How would I add values to EnumAura at runtime?

To clarify, all of my code must run after Aura Cascade is initialized.

Comment: You can't. They're are all basically final values behind the scenes, [for reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/478403/can-i-add-and-remove-elements-of-enumeration-at-runtime-in-java)

Comment: First answer in google [DUPLICATED]:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/478403/can-i-add-and-remove-elements-of-enumeration-at-runtime-in-java

Comment: An `enum` is a list of all possible values known at compile time.

Comment: I know normally you can't, but I wanted to be sure that there isn't some way to do it through reflection or some method forge provides before considering it impossible.

Answer (score 1):

if I understand your question correctly, you can't do that.

Please take a look to Java documentation about Enums : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

> **Enum Types**
>
> An enum type is a special data type that enables for a variable to be
>   a set of predefined constants. The variable must be equal to one of
>   the values that have been predefined for it. Common examples include
>   compass directions (values of NORTH, SOUTH, EAST, and WEST) and the
>   days of the week.
>
> Because they are constants, the names of an enum type's fields are in
>   uppercase letters.
>
> In the Java programming language, you define an enum type by using the
>   enum keyword. For example, you would specify a days-of-the-week enum
>   type as:

```
public enum Day {
 SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY,
 THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY  }
```

> You should use enum types any time you need to represent a fixed set of constants. That includes natural
>   enum types such as the planets in our solar system and data sets where
>   you know all possible values at compile time—for example, the choices
>   on a menu, command line flags, and so on.