# How to add values to an existing enums outside of the class in java

Tags: java, enums

How do you add more values to enums in java, I made some code to give an idea of what I'm going for but I know it doesn't work.

```
public class Types 
{
    public enum PieceTypes
    {}

    public void addTypes(String a)
    {
        PieceTypes = PieceTypes.values() + a;
    }

}
```

I have no idea where to start, please help.

Comment: You have a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478403/can-i-add-and-remove-elements-of-enumeration-at-runtime-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `enum` should be defined in compile time. yo can not change enum at run time.
You can use a `List<String>` or a `Map<String,integer>` and using simple string literals to simulate a dynamic enumeration.

Comment: Technically you _can_ add values. But you shouldn't.