# how to create dynamic enum and how to access that enum value directly

Tags: java, enums, enumeration

how to create dynamic enum and how to access that enum value directly.

Problem example:

```
enum Test{
   RED,
   GREEN
}
```

now i want to add Enum value BLUE dynamically and want to access it like Test.BLUE

kindly suggest solution.

Comment: Please provide an example of what you want to do. This question is not clear.

Comment: You can't. Take a look at that answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/478431/1369579